# Show splash screen and hide after finish web request

Tags: multithreading, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7.1, splash-screen

When my app start I want to show splash screen and create httpwebrequest and when request is finish hide splash screen and show main page.

This is my splash screen:

```
    private void ShowPopup()
    {
        this.popup = new Popup();
        this.popup.Child = new PopupSplash();
        this.popup.IsOpen = true;
        StartLoadingData();
    }

    private void StartLoadingData()
    {
        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                this.popup.IsOpen = false;
            }
        );
    }

    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        using (var db = new ListDataContext(ListDataContext.DBConnectionString))
        {
            if (!db.DatabaseExists())
            {
                db.CreateDatabase();
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
```

and this is my httpwebrequest:

```
    private void main_WebResponseAvailableEventHandler(object sender, string response, string url)
    {
            SearchResult result = new SearchResult(response, url);

            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["result"] = result;
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SearchPivotPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void HandleWebResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        WebRequestState state = (WebRequestState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebRequest request = state.Request;
        string url = request.RequestUri.ToString();
        state.Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

        if (state.Response != null)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(state.Response.GetResponseStream());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                sb.Append(reader.ReadLine());
            string text = sb.ToString();
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (WebResponseAvailable != null)
                {
                    WebResponseAvailable(this, text, url);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

in constructor MainPage()

```
        ....
        ShowPopup();
        HttpWebRequest movieRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebRequestState state = new WebRequestState();
        state.Request = movieRequest;
        movieRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(HandleWebResponse), state);
        WebResponseAvailable += main_WebResponseAvailableEventHandler;
        ....
```

Is there a way how can I do what I want? Or that both are in other thread this isn´t possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a fake splashScreen by adding a new `SplashScreenPage.xaml` page instead of SpalshScreen.jpg file. If you delete `SplashScreen.jpg` file the first page that should be loaded (from App.xaml) will be `SplashScreenPage.xaml` and there you can perform any operation like webrequest as you pointed out above. Once webrequest ends then do navigate to mainPage.xaml and then call `RemoveBackEntry` method in order to make `MainPage.xaml` the first page entry in the BackStack.

Regards,